# JavaScript Dynamic Text in Header Band (with Shopify)

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a dynamic text header band thanks to a code I have found and adapted to my needs.

[image]

```
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" scrollamount="3" scrolldelay="60" onmouseover="this.stop()" onmouseout="this.start()" bgcolor="#232F3E">
<strong>NOUVEAU : 1 article acheté = <u><a target="_blank" class="header" href=/pages/arbres title="1 article acheté = 1arbre – Trésor Ethnique">1 ARBRE PLANTÉ</a></u></strong> avec l’association <i>One Tree Planted</i>
&nbsp;&nbsp;·&nbsp;&nbsp; 
Première Commande: 10% de Réduction avec le Coupon BIENVENUE
&nbsp;&nbsp;·&nbsp;&nbsp; 
Livraison Suivie OFFERTE 
&nbsp;&nbsp;·&nbsp;&nbsp;  
Plus de 5.000 Clientes Satisfaites
 </marquee>
```

It works pretty well, but I was looking if I could make this one even better.

Indeed, I'd like instead the text to be on 4 different lines.

Every 3 seconds, it would switch (no scroll) to the next line of text (in a vertical movement)

The total sequence would then last 12 seconds

Here is the website: https://www.tresor-ethnique.com/

PS: 
I am using the CMS Shopify, and I have a theme installed.
As a result, I do not have any control on the HTML.

I just can integrate HTML content on a field.

How to do that?

PS: I use a theme, so I can just enter HTML into the field

I know how to integrate a Javascript code inside HTML if this is needed.

Comment: Yeah, unrelated to your question but you might want to get rid of that marquee tag. There are alternatives to it, CSS animations come to mind, but it is marked as obsolete and will most likely be removed sooner rather than later. New development probably shouldn't use it.

Comment: `<marquee>` has been marked as obsolete many years ago. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Comment: What you have here is a specification of a feature you want. People charge money for this kind of work. This is not what Stack Overflow is for.

Comment: oh okay thanks, I'll still look into it, keep you with news

Comment: Just to let you know guys, I've ended up with this solution. I have found other solutions regarding CSS animations, but the result was not quite what I wanted. Thank you for the time spent

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the second solution I came up with, using CSS animations

Anyway I couldn't manage to get the result I really want, cause the bar was refreshing before all the text was displayed

Anyway, I hope this solution would help anyone that would reach this post later:

Have a good day!

```
<span class="defileParent">
<span class="defile">
<strong>NOUVEAU : 1 article acheté = <u><a target="_blank" class="header" href=/pages/arbres title="1 article acheté = 1arbre – Trésor Ethnique">1 ARBRE PLANTÉ</a></u></strong> avec l’association <i>One Tree Planted</i>
&nbsp;&nbsp;·&nbsp;&nbsp; 
Première Commande: 10% de Réduction avec le Coupon BIENVENUE
&nbsp;&nbsp;·&nbsp;&nbsp; 
Livraison Suivie OFFERTE 
&nbsp;&nbsp;·&nbsp;&nbsp;  
Plus de 5.000 Clientes Satisfaites
</span>
</span>
<style type="text/css">

.defileParent {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 860px;
}

.defile {
    display:block;
    -webkit-animation:linear marqueelike 15s infinite ;
    -moz-animation:linear marqueelike 15s infinite ;
    -o-animation:linear marqueelike 15s infinite ;
    -ms-animation:linear marqueelike 15s infinite ;
    animation:linear marqueelike 15s infinite ;
    margin-left:-100%;
    padding:0 5px;
    text-align:left;
    height:25px;
}

.defile:after {
    content:attr(data-text);
    position:absolute;
    white-space:nowrap;
    padding-left:10px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes marqueelike {
    0%, 100% {margin-left:0;}
    99.99% {margin-left:-100%;}
 }
@-moz-keyframes marqueelike {
    0%, 100% {margin-left:0;}
    99.99% {margin-left:-100%;}
 }
@-o-keyframes marqueelike {
    0%, 100% {margin-left:0;}
    99.99% {margin-left:-100%;}
 }
@-ms-keyframes marqueelike {
    0%, 100% {margin-left:0;}
    99.99% {margin-left:-100%;}
 }
@keyframes marqueelike {
    0%, 100% {margin-left:0;}
    99.99% {margin-left:-100%;}
 }

 @media only screen and (max-width: 860px) {
.defileParent {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

.defile {
    display:block;
    -webkit-animation:linear marqueelike 15s infinite ;
    -moz-animation:linear marqueelike 15s infinite ;
    -o-animation:linear marqueelike 15s infinite ;
    -ms-animation:linear marqueelike 15s infinite ;
    animation:linear marqueelike 15s infinite ;
    margin-left:-100%;
    padding:0 5px;
    text-align:left;
    height:25px;
}
}
</style>






@media only screen and (max-width: 860px) {
.defileParent {
    display: block;
    margin: 3em auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

.defile {
    display:block;
    -webkit-animation:linear marqueelike 15s infinite ;
    -moz-animation:linear marqueelike 15s infinite ;
    -o-animation:linear marqueelike 15s infinite ;
    -ms-animation:linear marqueelike 15s infinite ;
    animation:linear marqueelike 15s infinite ;
    margin-left:-100%;
    padding:0 5px;
    text-align:left;
    height:25px;
}
}
```

Comment: why a downvote for providing another solution by myself? :(